# In javascript, is there an events to check if a variable name have just created?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing some code for my chrome extension to inject some scripts to some page.

I want to change a property value right after it is created in the `window` object.

Is there an event to check if a property has just been added to an object?

Comment: @DanielA.White — Isn't that for DOM changes rather than variable changes?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about creating a setter method for the property of the window object you are searching for?

Check out the code in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j6jagzan/1/

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "myprop",
    (function() {
    var prop;
        return {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            get: function() {
                return prop;
            },
            set: function(value) {
                console.log("object has been set to " + value);
                //Your code here
                prop = value;
            }
        }
    })()
);

//Set the global property
myprop = 3;
```

It uses an "immediately-invoked function expression" (IIFE) to store the value of the property in a closure.

Of course, this will only work if the property is created by an assignment expression like `prop = value` or `window["prop"] = value`

Comment: **@the_tiger** your answer is the best ^^ that's what i need now. Because i know the variable name, so i can use `set: function(){}` in your code to change the value of it. Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Good answer. But I have to say that it's substantially the same as @Quentin's one and it came after.

Comment: @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: @AndreaCasaccia you are right, it's almost the same approach as in Quentin's answer (which I noticed after submitting mine) but it fits the needs of the OP better, as he mentioned that he has no control over the code which sets the variable.

Comment: You are right, it's not the very same thing. @Quentin is defining an object with setter and getter, while you are using `Object.defineProperty` on the `window` object, which obviously couldn't be redefined. My bad for not noticing the difference between the two answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't.

If you need this, then you are probably best off using an object with a setter function.

```js
var o = {
  set myValue(str) {
      this._str = str;
      alert(str);
    },
    get myValue() {
      return this._str;
    }
}

o.myValue = "Hello";
document.body.innerHTML = o.myValue;
```

Comment: i'm sorry because the page is the host of variable to create, i don't have the right to change the way how he create a variable. So this way is not good for me at this time.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Object.observe()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) API is what you are looking for. At the time of writing this, it's an experimental technology, part of the ECMAScript 2016 (ES7) proposal.

In the meantime you can use [observe-js](https://github.com/polymer/observe-js), which will leverage `Object.observe()` where available.

You could use a `PathObserver` to observe just the property you are interested in (for example `window.myProperty`):

```
var observer = new PathObserver(window, 'myProperty');
observer.open(function(newValue, oldValue) {
  // respond to window.myProperty having changed value.
});
```

Comment: Thanks **Andrea Casaccia** so much, but maybe you right, i've tested it, the performance is a big thing to mantain. I see the `Object.defineProperty` of **the_tiger** is too good answer for this question. We should learn it.

Comment: That's true @TrầnQuốcHoàinew2015 the other answers are simpler and work well for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not an event that checks if a variable name is created.

What you could do, is use an interval to check for a variable, then once it's defined, do something.  Here is some pseudo-code:

```
setInterval(function() {
  if (theVariable !== 'undefined')
    // yay, it's been defined!
}, 1000)
```

Comment: thanks **sircapsalot**, but if we check every 1s that's not good, because i want to change the value of variable right after he created, and the page will use new value for the next line of code in the page. Change and apply right away because the next line need new value. So in 1s, i think all the code in page is executed. But if we change to smaller time, the page will crash.

Comment: @sircapsalot — Not true. Browsers enforce a minimum delay. Even if that wasn't the case, they still wouldn't interrupt another function to run an event handler.

Comment: deleted the comment about minimum delay @Quentin .  didn't know that